# Weird phenomenon : computer only boot if I plug-in a specific USB device while pressing the power button, once in 10~20 tries

Tags: boot, usb, motherboard, power-supply, computer-building

I've got my hands on a very, very **weird** issue. I spent months trying everything, and google had literally 0 similar problem to help me.

To summarize, it's a computer I built myself 5 years ago. Since last year, pressing POWER doesn't boot the computer. There is still electrity since all the internal leds etc. are on.

After plugging everything out and in, I noticed one very specific way of turning on the computer :

1. I unplug my USB audio interface (scarlet 2i2), I press power button
2. Right now nothing is happening
3. I plug the device back in, then the computer boot by itself the very second I do that.

However with time, it started to work less and less, and recently I need to fiddle with the usb plug for at least 2min until it finally boot.

I replaced the motherboard battery and honnestly at this point I'm only left with replacing the power supply or motherboard, but that's quite a burden, and it may not resolve the issue, so I'm hoping some people maybe could have an idea. If I ever lose my usb audio interface, I will have no way to boot my computer since only this very device do the trick for some reason.

Thanks in advance.

*Ps : I run a CPU i7 2600K 3.4 GHz+ 8Go RAM DDR3 + Nvidia GeForce GTX 1060 + 2 SSD (256Go & 1to) + 2 DD 7200Tr/min (1To & 2to), CoolerMaster HAF 932 Adv case + ASUS p8z77-v motherboard. Dual boot with w7 & ubuntu. Corsaire ax650 gold PSU.*

Comment: Pressing the Power button by default doesn't normally do anything unless held for 5 seconds, when it will power off immediately (not OS shut-down). However, the OS can be configured to allow a specific action on pressing it. Maybe OS updates have changed this setting.

Comment: My issue is the opposite, I'm trying to power ON the computer. I don't think it's OS related since I can't even get the computer to boot.

Comment: But you say the internals have electricity? Please clarify: when you press the power button, are any LED's in the machine already on?

Comment: Maybe it's a faulty switch in the Power button, so try manually shorting the pins to which the Power button is connected.

Comment: @varfirstName Yes, the internal pieces like motherboard or GPU have light before I do anything. Just pressing the power button does nothing.

Comment: @AFH I actually replaced to the power button and the cable, and tried to jump the pins too but it didn't change anything sadly.

Comment: @HélèneAluyis That means there is power going to the motherboard already. Is there any video output at this point or no?

Comment: @varfirstName Nop, there is literally nothing happening. Just the leds showing the power is reaching the motherboard. Nothing happen until I plug out/in multiple time my usb audio interface while pressing the Power button.

Comment: Do you have a reset switch on your case? Try using that.

Comment: @varfirstName I tried it before without success.

Comment: Is the USB port you are talking about part of the case, or part of the mobo?

Comment: @varfirstName it's not related to a specific usb port, it works with any usb port. Just a specific device, which I need to plug in to even hope the computer starts.

Comment: that's odd. I'm almost wondering if there's a short somewhere.

Comment: If you plug in the USB device and get the machine to boot and then unplug that device does the machine stay booted? What happens when you restart from the OS once booted and unplug the device or variations at this level. I assume the device does not have its own external power source. The good news is you should be able to troubleshoot the PSU more by using a voltmeter, etc. and testing the output voltages per the Corsair ax650 gold wiring diagram so try to find and do that or reach out to support and see if they can help you get the doc so you can eliminate more at this level. Keep digging!!

Comment: @PimpJuiceIT Yes, once the "plug in usb after I pressed Power" trick is done, everything works fine, I can unplug or plug anything without issue. The device has no power source itself.
I actually just tested the PSU with my multimeter, after shorting 15 & 16 to make the PSU start, I only get the +5VSB "stand by", all other are at 0. The issue is maybe in the exchange between the motherboard and the PSU, like if it's not sending PWR_GOOD or something.

Comment: All others are at 0 testing from their cable terminal or the terminals in the PSU itself. I'd eliminate as granular and core as possible if you know what I'm saying. Leave no stone unturned and help eliminate possible oversight at another level. Highly unlikely all the cables would be bad at one but just be thorough. If so, it sounds like you have have confirmed a PSU output issue. May be worth a call to support though. I assume it I has no internal fuses either or how dangerous opening it and checking is either. I think some have internal fuses sometimes but its electrically hazardous to see.

Comment: I think it'd be worth a call to support and try to ask them simple questions like do the terminals not output power unless all cables are connected, a common issue that could cause this, etc. I know one time I had an issue with a two PSU high performance GPU machine for a client and I couldn't figure it out and it was a simple cable issue or something I forgot to do to get the PSU to work correctly. A simple phone call helped me figure that out so I don't think you have much to loose but a little time and effort just in case.

Comment: @PimpJuiceIT I only checked from the cable terminal indeed. Getting into the PSU itself is a bit out of my knowledge so I guess I'll have to contact support for that. However since the computer works fine once it's booted, I don't think there are many damages inside the PSU itself.

Comment: May be a mobo problem which can also be troubleshot or run through some diag test perhaps. The BIOS/firmware may have diagnostics tests built into it and/or you may be able to get a diag boot disk for the mobo perhaps. Just some quick ideas since you don't have redundant and  known-good hardware to try or whatever.